# Left Join Subset of Column Based on Date Interval

Tags: r, left-join, lubridate

I have two dataframes: `df1` - series of MRI reads for subject 1 by 2 different MRI readers; `df2` - list of steroid use for subject 1

I am trying to perform a left join of `df2$STATUS` to `df1` based on whether `df1$DOS` is contained within the `lubridate::interval(start = df2$START_DATE, end = df2$STOP_DATE)`. If there is no `df2$STATUS` available for that `df1$DOS`, I want the value to be `NA`.

As example, the final df should look something like this, since `df1$DOS` falls within the first row `lubridate::interval(start = df2$START_DATE, end = df2$STOP_DATE)`:

[image: left join example]

**dput examples**

```
df1 = structure(list(SUBJID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), READER = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    DOS = structure(c(15469, 15497, 15530, 15579, 15635, 15691, 
    15747, 15805, 15901, 16010, 16101, 16202, 16293, 16422, 16547, 
    16678, 16841, 17035, 17217, 17331, 17372, 17497, 17588, 17652, 
    17686, 17714, 17770, 17826, 17882, 17938, 17994, 18050, 18079, 
    18113, 18176, 15469, 15497, 15530, 15579, 15635, 15691, 15747, 
    15805, 15901, 16010, 16101, 16202, 16293, 16422, 16547, 16678, 
    16841, 17035, 17217, 17331, 17372, 17497, 17588, 17652, 17686, 
    17714, 17770, 17826, 17882, 17938, 17994, 18050, 18079, 18113, 
    18176), class = "Date"), VISIT = c("1 Screening", "1 Week 04", 
    "1 Week 08", "1 Week 16", "Unscheduled 01", "Unscheduled 02", 
    "Unscheduled 03", "Unscheduled 04", "Unscheduled 05", "Unscheduled 06", 
    "Unscheduled 07", "Unscheduled 08", "Unscheduled 09", "Unscheduled 10", 
    "Unscheduled 11", "Unscheduled 12", "Unscheduled 13", "Unscheduled 14", 
    "Unscheduled 15", "Unscheduled", "Unscheduled 16", "Unscheduled 17", 
    "Unscheduled", "2 Screening", "2 Week 04", "2 Week 08", "2 Week 16", 
    "Unscheduled 18", "Unscheduled 19", "Unscheduled 20", "Unscheduled 21", 
    "Unscheduled 22", "Unscheduled 23", "Unscheduled 24", "Unscheduled 25", 
    "1 Screening", "1 Week 04", "1 Week 08", "1 Week 16", "Unscheduled 01", 
    "Unscheduled 02", "Unscheduled 03", "Unscheduled 04", "Unscheduled 05", 
    "Unscheduled 06", "Unscheduled 07", "Unscheduled 08", "Unscheduled 09", 
    "Unscheduled 10", "Unscheduled 11", "Unscheduled 12", "Unscheduled 13", 
    "Unscheduled 14", "Unscheduled 15", "Unscheduled", "Unscheduled 16", 
    "Unscheduled 17", "Unscheduled", "2 Screening", "2 Week 04", 
    "2 Week 08", "2 Week 16", "Unscheduled 18", "Unscheduled 19", 
    "Unscheduled 20", "Unscheduled 21", "Unscheduled 22", "Unscheduled 23", 
    "Unscheduled 24", "Unscheduled 25"), MOS_DUR = c(0, 0.903225806451613, 
    2, 3.58064516129032, 5.41935483870968, 7.25806451612903, 
    9.07142857142857, 11.0333333333333, 14.1935483870968, 17.741935483871, 
    20.7096774193548, 24.0967741935484, 27.0645161290323, 31.2903225806452, 
    35.4333333333333, 39.7096774193548, 45.0344827586207, 51.4193548387097, 
    57.3928571428571, 61.1666666666667, 62.5161290322581, 66.6, 
    69.6071428571429, 71.7333333333333, 72.8387096774194, 73.7666666666667, 
    75.5806451612903, 77.4193548387097, 79.258064516129, 81.0714285714286, 
    82.9677419354839, 84.8064516129032, 85.7666666666667, 86.8709677419355, 
    88.9333333333333, 0, 0.903225806451613, 2, 3.58064516129032, 
    5.41935483870968, 7.25806451612903, 9.07142857142857, 11.0333333333333, 
    14.1935483870968, 17.741935483871, 20.7096774193548, 24.0967741935484, 
    27.0645161290323, 31.2903225806452, 35.4333333333333, 39.7096774193548, 
    45.0344827586207, 51.4193548387097, 57.3928571428571, 61.1666666666667, 
    62.5161290322581, 66.6, 69.6071428571429, 71.7333333333333, 
    72.8387096774194, 73.7666666666667, 75.5806451612903, 77.4193548387097, 
    79.258064516129, 81.0714285714286, 82.9677419354839, 84.8064516129032, 
    85.7666666666667, 86.8709677419355, 88.9333333333333), DAYS_DUR = c(0, 
    28, 61, 110, 166, 222, 278, 336, 432, 541, 632, 733, 824, 
    953, 1078, 1209, 1372, 1566, 1748, 1862, 1903, 2028, 2119, 
    2183, 2217, 2245, 2301, 2357, 2413, 2469, 2525, 2581, 2610, 
    2644, 2707, 0, 28, 61, 110, 166, 222, 278, 336, 432, 541, 
    632, 733, 824, 953, 1078, 1209, 1372, 1566, 1748, 1862, 1903, 
    2028, 2119, 2183, 2217, 2245, 2301, 2357, 2413, 2469, 2525, 
    2581, 2610, 2644, 2707), SPD = c(1845.52, 1658.84, 1924.06, 
    1914.49, 2094.22, 1890.46, 1369.93, 985.96, 570.47, 348.88, 
    500.76, 416.6, 407.92, 409.56, 362.33, 329.35, 326.93, 267.39, 
    304.2, 825.13, 399.47, 438.16, 800.82, 1947.56, 2357.86, 
    2959.97, 3066.57, 4235.27, 3308.1, 5321.45, 2840.12, 4162.53, 
    5379.55, 4132.86, 6570.47, 1375.57, 1744.6, 2522.15, 1828.55, 
    2013.06, 1555.05, 1294.24, 1048.76, 439.1, 402, 276.74, 121.37, 
    142.34, 72.9, 264.92, 62.27, 72.96, 68.91, 51.56, 251.33, 
    86.53, 134.48, 337.51, 1209.22, 1158.13, 1165.09, 2432.43, 
    2141.32, 3463.67, 5276.63, 3883.76, 4004.92, 4678.29, 4942.69, 
    5159.52), SPD_NADIR = c(1845.52, 1658.84, 1658.84, 1658.84, 
    1658.84, 1658.84, 1369.93, 985.96, 570.47, 348.88, 348.88, 
    348.88, 348.88, 348.88, 348.88, 329.35, 326.93, 267.39, 267.39, 
    267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 
    267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 267.39, 
    1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1294.24, 
    1048.76, 439.1, 402, 276.74, 121.37, 121.37, 72.9, 72.9, 
    62.27, 62.27, 62.27, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 
    51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 51.56, 
    51.56, 51.56), PCT_DIFF_NADIR = c(NA, -0.101153062551476, 
    0.15988280967423, 0.154113718019821, 0.262460514576451, 0.139627691639941, 
    -0.174163873550192, -0.280284394093129, -0.421406547932979, 
    -0.38843409819973, 0.435335932125659, 0.194106856225636, 
    0.169227241458381, 0.173927998165558, 0.0385519376289841, 
    -0.0559791332263242, -0.00734780628510708, -0.182118496314196, 
    0.137664086166274, 2.0858670855305, 0.493960133138861, 0.638655147911291, 
    1.99495119488388, 6.28359325330042, 7.81805602303751, 10.0698605033846, 
    10.4685291147762, 14.8392984030816, 11.3718164478851, 18.9014548038446, 
    9.62163880474214, 14.5672613037137, 19.1187404166199, 14.4562997868282, 
    23.5726092972811, NA, 0.268274242677581, 0.833530827220716, 
    0.329303488735579, 0.463436975217546, 0.13047682051804, -0.0591245810827511, 
    -0.189671158363209, -0.581315076852664, -0.0844910043270326, 
    -0.311592039800995, -0.561429500614295, 0.172777457361786, 
    -0.399357337068468, 2.63401920438957, -0.145816186556927, 
    0.171671752047535, 0.106632407258712, -0.171992933997109, 
    3.87451512800621, 0.678238944918541, 1.60822342901474, 5.54596586501164, 
    22.4526764934057, 21.4617920868891, 21.5967804499612, 46.1766873545384, 
    40.5306439100078, 66.1774631497285, 101.339604344453, 74.3250581846393, 
    76.6749418153607, 89.7348719937936, 94.8628782001551, 99.0682699767261
    ), SPD_BL = c(1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 
    1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 
    1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 
    1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 
    1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 1845.52, 
    1845.52, 1845.52, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 
    1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 
    1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 
    1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 
    1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 1375.57, 
    1375.57, 1375.57), PCT_DIFF_BL = c(NA, -0.101153062551476, 
    0.042557111274871, 0.0373715809094456, 0.134758767176731, 
    0.024350860462092, -0.257699726906238, -0.465754909185487, 
    -0.690889288655772, -0.810958429060644, -0.728661840565261, 
    -0.77426416402965, -0.778967445489618, -0.77807880705709, 
    -0.803670510208505, -0.821540812345572, -0.822852095886254, 
    -0.855114005808661, -0.835168407820018, -0.552901079370584, 
    -0.783546100827951, -0.762581819758117, -0.566073518574711, 
    0.0552906497897611, 0.277612813732715, 0.60386774459231, 
    0.661629242706663, 1.29489249642377, 0.792502926004595, 1.88344206510902, 
    0.53892669816637, 1.25547813082492, 1.91492370713945, 1.23940136113399, 
    2.56022692791192, NA, 0.268274242677581, 0.833530827220716, 
    0.329303488735579, 0.463436975217546, 0.13047682051804, -0.0591245810827511, 
    -0.237581511664256, -0.680786873805041, -0.707757511431625, 
    -0.798817944561164, -0.911767485478747, -0.896522895963128, 
    -0.947003787520809, -0.807410746090711, -0.954731493126486, 
    -0.946960169238934, -0.949904403265555, -0.96251735644133, 
    -0.817290286935598, -0.93709516782134, -0.902236890888868, 
    -0.754639894734546, -0.120931686500869, -0.158072653518178, 
    -0.153012932820576, 0.768306956388988, 0.556678322440879, 
    1.51798890641698, 2.83595891157847, 1.82338230697093, 1.91146215750562, 
    2.40098286528494, 2.59319409408463, 2.75082329507041), NLFLG = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), CLINDET_DT = structure(c(18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 
    18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177, 18177), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-70L), groups = structure(list(SUBJID = c(1, 1), READER = structure(c(1L, 
4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:35, 36:70), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 = structure(list(SUBJID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), DRUG = structure(c("Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", 
"Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", 
"Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", 
"Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone", 
"Dexamethasone", "Dexamethasone"), label = "Agent Name", format.sas = "$"), 
    ROUTE = structure(c("PO", "IVI", "IVI", "PO", "PO", "PO", 
    "PO", "PO", "IVI", "PO", "PO", "PO", "PO", "PO", "PO", "PO"
    ), label = "Route", format.sas = "$"), START_DT = structure(c(15455, 
    15469, 15470, 15471, 15472, 15473, 15474, 15475, 17653, 18061, 
    18079, 18115, 18122, 18129, 18136, 18142), class = "Date"), 
    STOP_DT = structure(c(15468, 15469, 15470, 15471, 15472, 
    15473, 15474, 15475, 17653, 18067, 18114, 18121, 18128, 18135, 
    18141, NA), class = "Date"), DAYS_DUR = c(13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 35, 6, 6, 6, 5, NA), DEXEQ = c(0, 10, 30, 
    8, 8, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 8), PHYSFLAG = c(0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), STATUS = c("STABLE", 
    "INCREASE", "INCREASE", "INCREASE", "INCREASE", "INCREASE", 
    "STABLE", "STABLE", "INCREASE", "INCREASE", "INCREASE", "INCREASE", 
    "INCREASE", "INCREASE", "STABLE", "INCREASE")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), groups = structure(list(SUBJID = 1, .rows = structure(list(
    1:16), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

example  = structure(list(SUBJID = 1, READER = structure(1L, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), DOS = structure(15469, class = "Date"), 
    VISIT = "1 Screening", MOS_DUR = 0, DAYS_DUR = 0, SPD = 1845.52, 
    SPD_NADIR = 1845.52, PCT_DIFF_NADIR = NA_real_, SPD_BL = 1845.52, 
    PCT_DIFF_BL = NA_real_, NLFLG = 0, CLINDET_DT = structure(18177, class = "Date"), 
    STATUS = "STABLE"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please post example data for example via `dput()`

Comment: Please read the information on posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  Note that a complete self contained example is required including all inputs, code and library statements and images should not be used for input since then no one other than you can easily use it except by retyping it all

Comment: @Daniel and @G.Grothendieck - Added `dput()` examples. My apologies. I also added the example as a dataset in addition the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using `foverlaps` in the `data.table` package (and `dplyr` just for some cleaning). Basically we are treating the DOS variable as an interval here by setting same value for start and end date and then we join via overlapping intervals.

Another solution would be to `full_join` by ID and then e.g. use `%within%` from `lubridate` but this would not preserve the rows for which there is no match.

Note that we cannot include those rows in `df2` which have NA dates for the start or end variable. These are therefore removed before the join.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1 %>% mutate(start = DOS, end = DOS))
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2 %>% 
                       select(SUBJID, start = START_DT, end =STOP_DT, STATUS) %>%
                       filter(!is.na(start)&!is.na(end)))
setkey(dt1, SUBJID, start, end)
setkey(dt2, SUBJID, start, end)
df3 <- foverlaps(dt1, dt2, type="within") %>% 
  select(-i.start, -i.end)
```

#### `Tidyverse` solution

Here we apply one full join and filter to find all the matches and then one full join with the original `df1` data set to keep the rows with no match at all.

```
library(lubridate)

df3 <- df1 %>% 
  full_join(df1 %>%
              full_join(df2 %>% 
                          select(SUBJID,START_DT, STOP_DT, STATUS), by = "SUBJID") %>%
              filter(DOS %within% interval(START_DT, STOP_DT)))
```

Comment: would you also be able to add the `lubridate`/`full_join` solution? I typically work within a tidyverse framework rather than `data.table`. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, please see my edit.