# Applying a function to rows but referencing different table

Tags: r

I have 2 tables

```
df1 = data.frame("dates" = c(seq(as.Date("2020-1-1"), as.Date("2020-1-10"), by = "days")))
df2 = data.frame("observations" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), "start" = as.Date(c("2019-12-30", "2020-1-1", "2020-1-5","2020-1-10")), "end"=as.Date(c("2020-1-3", "2020-1-2", "2020-1-12","2020-1-14")))
```

I would like to know the number of observation periods that occur on each day of df1, based on the start/stop dates in df2. E.g. on 1/1/2020, observations a and b were in progress, hence "2".

The expected output would be as follows:

[image]

I've tried using sums

```
df1$number = sum(as.Date(df2$start) <= df1$dates & as.Date(df2$end)>=df1$dates)
```

But that only sums up the entire column values

I've then tried to create a custom function for this:

```
df1$number = apply(df1, 1, function(x) sum(df2$start <= x & df2$end>=x))
```

But it returns an NA value.

I then tried to do embed an "ifelse" within it, but get the same issue with NAs

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) sum(ifelse(df2$start <= x & df2$end>=x, 1, 0)))
```

Can anyone suggest what the issue is? Thanks!

edit: an interval join was suggested which is not what I'm trying to get - I think naming the observations with a numeric label was what caused confusion. I am trying to find out the TOTAL number of observations with periods that fall within the day, as compared to doing a 1:1 match.

Regards
Sing

Comment: This is basically an interval join. Closing this as a duplicate. If you continue to have issues please edit your post and explain how the solutions from the dupe posts did not work.

Comment: On closer inspection: I don't understand your expected output. Can you explain why e.g. `number = 2` for `dates = 1/01/2020`? The expected output doesn't seem to match you sample input data.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers , for date 1/1/2020 , observation 1 and 2 have periods that include this date, hence number = 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the comparison in a function `f` and pass it through `outer`, `rowSums` is what you're looking for.

```
f <- \(x, y) df1[x, 1] >= df2[y, 2] & df1[x, 1] <= df2[y, 3]
cbind(df1, number=rowSums(outer(1:nrow(df1), 1:nrow(df2), f)))
#         dates number
# 1  2020-01-01      2
# 2  2020-01-02      2
# 3  2020-01-03      1
# 4  2020-01-04      0
# 5  2020-01-05      1
# 6  2020-01-06      1
# 7  2020-01-07      1
# 8  2020-01-08      1
# 9  2020-01-09      1
# 10 2020-01-10      2
```

Comment: Thanks that's pretty neat.  Just for learning - my first instinct for this approach would have been to use mapply instead of outer, which doesn't work...could you explain why?

cbind(df1, number=rowSums(mapply(f, 1:nrow(df1), 1:nrow(df2))))

Comment: You're welcome @TanSingChee. Sure, `mapply` applies a function in sequence to the opposing positions of two vectors, while `outer` does this to every other position each time. Or in other words, for jobs where you might use a single `for` loop, you would use `mapply`, and for double `for` loops,  `outer`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution using [dplyr/tidyverse functions](https://www.tidyverse.org/) and the [`%within%` function from the lubridate package](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/within-interval.html). This approach is similar to [Left Join Subset of Column Based on Date Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288212/left-join-subset-of-column-based-on-date-interval), however there are some important differences i.e. use `summarise()` instead of `filter()` to avoid 'losing' dates where "number" == 0, and join by 'character()' as there are no common columns between datasets:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 = data.frame("dates" = c(seq(as.Date("2020-1-1"), 
                                 as.Date("2020-1-10"),
                                 by = "days")))
df2 = data.frame("observations" = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
                 "start" = as.Date(c("2019-12-30", "2020-1-1", "2020-1-5","2020-1-10")), 
                 "end"=as.Date(c("2020-1-3", "2020-1-2", "2020-1-12","2020-1-14")))
df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = character()) %>%
  mutate(number = dates %within% interval(start, end)) %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  summarise(number = sum(number))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    dates      number
#>    <date>      <dbl>
#>  1 2020-01-01      2
#>  2 2020-01-02      2
#>  3 2020-01-03      1
#>  4 2020-01-04      0
#>  5 2020-01-05      1
#>  6 2020-01-06      1
#>  7 2020-01-07      1
#>  8 2020-01-08      1
#>  9 2020-01-09      1
#> 10 2020-01-10      2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Does this approach work with your actual data?

Comment: Very nice +1. You don't even need the `ifelse` as `%within%` already returns a logical `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector that you can sum.

Comment: Yes - great point - I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @jared_mamrot that worked - the only issue is my main dataset has more than 800 000 observations so the join does take a while!

Comment: Yep, it will take ages. You could also use data.table to speed things up, but if @jay.sf's method works on your 'large' dataset, I'd go with that (it's very clever +1)